# OpenCV Image Coordinates to World Coordinates Conversion Issue

Tags: java, opencv, coordinate-systems, ransac, opencv-solvepnp

I am trying to capture an image of an object with a monocular camera and with :

1. First a normal calibration of the camera
2. And then a perspective calibration of the camera using known object coordinates in both the world-system and camera-system

After these two steps I should be able to obtain the world coordinates of any detected object in the frame. This [link](https://www.fdxlabs.com/calculate-x-y-z-real-world-coordinates-from-a-single-camera-using-opencv/) explains what I'm trying to do in a more detailed pattern, but unlike the link I am not using OpenCV with Python but with Java.

So far I have managed to do the normal calibration, obtained the camera intrinsic parameters and rotation/translation vectors. I used these parameters in the solvePnPRansac() OpenCv function to obtain the extrinsic matrix of the camera, which allowed to build the projection matrix to convert points from the world-coordinates to image coodinates. Here are the obtained parameters :

[image: Intrinsic Params]
[image: Distorsion Coefficients]

[image: New Optimal Camera Matrix]

[image: Rotation and Translation vectors]

[image: Extrinsic Parameters]

From this step I have everything I need to conduct the two operations shown in the first link :

[image]
[image]

Now this is where things get complicated. When I use the world-system coordinates, I obtain the right image-system coordinates as obtained with the object detection algorithm (+- a few pixels). However, when I try to do the second operation, the obtained results make no sense at all. First here's the code that I used to obtain the extrinsic parameters :

```
        double[] cx = this.optMat.get(0, 2);
        double[] cy = this.optMat.get(1, 2);
        int realCenterX = 258;
        int realCenterY = 250;
        int realCenterZ = 453;
        MatOfPoint3f worldPoints = new MatOfPoint3f();
        MatOfPoint2f imagePoints = new MatOfPoint2f();
        
        List<Point3> objPoints = new ArrayList<Point3>();
        objPoints.add(new Point3(realCenterX,realCenterY,realCenterZ));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(154,169,475));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(244,169,470));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(337,169,470));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(154,240,469));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(244,240,452));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(337,240,462));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(154,310,472));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(244,310,460));
        objPoints.add(new Point3(337,310,468));
        worldPoints.fromList(objPoints);
        
        List<Point> imgPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
        imgPoints.add(new Point(cx[0],cy[0]));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(569,99));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(421,100));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(272,100));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(571,212));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(422,213));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(273,214));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(574,327));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(423,328));
        imgPoints.add(new Point(273,330));
        imagePoints.fromList(imgPoints);

        for(int i= 0;i<worldPoints.rows();i++) {    
            for(int j=0;j<worldPoints.cols();j++) {
                double[] pointI = worldPoints.get(i, j);
                double wX = pointI[0]-realCenterX;      
                double wY = pointI[1]-realCenterY;
                double wD = pointI[2];
                double D1 = Math.sqrt((wX*wX)+(wY+wY));
                double wZ = Math.sqrt((wD*wD)+(D1*D1));
                pointI[2] = wZ;
                worldPoints.put(i, j, pointI);
            }
        }
        
        Mat optMatInv = new Mat();
        Core.invert(this.optMat, optMatInv);
        Calib3d.solvePnPRansac(worldPoints, imagePoints, optMat, distCoeffs, rvecsPnP, tvecsPnP, true, 100, (float) 0.5, 0.99, new Mat(), Calib3d.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE);
        Calib3d.Rodrigues(this.rvecsPnP, this.rodriguesVecs);
        this.rodriguesVecs.copyTo(this.extrinsicMat);
        List<Mat> concat = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        concat.add(this.rodriguesVecs);
        concat.add(this.tvecsPnP);
        Core.hconcat(concat, this.extrinsicMat);
        Core.gemm(this.optMat, this.extrinsicMat, 1, new Mat(), 0, this.projectionMat);
        int nbOfElements = worldPoints.rows() * worldPoints.cols();
        List<Double> sDescribe = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

For the first operation (from world-system to image-system) :

```
        for(int i= 0;i<nbOfElements;i++) {  
                double[] pointArray = worldPoints.get(i,0);
                Mat pointI = new Mat(1,4,CvType.CV_64F);
                pointI.put(0, 0, pointArray[0]);
                pointI.put(0, 1, pointArray[1]);
                pointI.put(0, 2, pointArray[2]);
                pointI.put(0, 3, 1);
                Mat transPointI = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_64F);
                Core.transpose(pointI,transPointI);
                Mat sUV = new Mat(3,1,CvType.CV_64F);
                Core.gemm(projectionMat, transPointI, 1, new Mat(), 0, sUV);
                double[] sArray0 = sUV.get(2,0);
                double s = sArray0[0];
                Mat UV = new Mat();
                Core.multiply(sUV, new Scalar(1/s,1/s,1/s), UV);
                sDescribe.add(i, s);    
        }
```

Which has pretty good results, like for the (154,169,475), the obtained result was :

[image: Obtained Image Point]

And the code for the second operation (from image system to world system) :

```
        for(int i= 0;i<nbOfElements;i++) {  
                double[] pointArray = imagePoints.get(i, 0);
                double sPoint = sDescribe.get(i);
                Mat pointI = new Mat(3,1,CvType.CV_64F);
                pointI.put(0, 0, pointArray[0]);
                pointI.put(1, 0, pointArray[1]);
                pointI.put(2, 0, 1);
                Mat transPointI = new Mat();
                Core.transpose(pointI, transPointI);
                Mat sUV = new Mat(3,1,CvType.CV_64F);
                Core.multiply(transPointI, new Scalar(sPoint,sPoint,sPoint), sUV);
                Mat invCameraMatrix = new Mat(3,3,CvType.CV_64F);
                Core.invert(this.optMat, invCameraMatrix);
                Mat tmp1 = new Mat();
                Core.gemm(sUV,invCameraMatrix,  1, new Mat(), 0, tmp1);
                Mat tVecsInv = new Mat();
                Core.transpose(this.tvecsPnP, tVecsInv);
                Mat tmp2 = new Mat();
                Core.subtract(tmp1, tVecsInv, tmp2);
                Mat XYZ = new Mat();
                Mat inverseRMat = new Mat();
                Core.invert(this.rodriguesVecs, inverseRMat);
                Core.gemm(tmp2, inverseRMat, 1, new Mat(), 0, XYZ);
        }
```

Which for the same point returned coordinates like :

[image: World coordinates point]

I'm really lost as to where the problem might be coming from. I revised to code many times but the algorithm doesn't seem wrong. I am however suspecting the obtained extrinsic parameters, especially the Z value of tVecsPnP which is too high considering that it should be close to its X value according to my Camera/World setup, but I don't reallt know how to fix it. If anyone has any clue on how to overcome this please let me know :) Thank you !